# Add a program that requires Adminstrator to STARTUP

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, registry, startup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run a program automatically as admin on Windows startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427673/how-to-run-a-program-automatically-as-admin-on-windows-startup)

I've a program written in C++ which requires administrator to run it(it can't be run as user). I'm trying to run this program whenever the user log in, I tried to add a "string" to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

and

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

but it works only with application that doesn't require administrator privileges, it has no effect on my program.

I've managed to solve it by creating a BAT file adding it to the registry, which starts my program.However, it launches the dialog which asks for Admin access. thus we can understand that I can not start it up using this method.

I guess there should be some method, for example an antivirus has administrator privileges. but it could find any thing about it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Task scheduler, look here for details:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/make-vista-launch-uac-restricted-programs-at-startup-with-task-scheduler/616

Comment: I need it to be launched by it self, I don't want the user to be able to cancel the startup.

Comment: @kirill Tough; the user owns the PC, you don't. Imagine if it was possible to do what you want - can you see how to write a virus that way?

Comment: The user can cancel any type of startup - including the one that you mentioned in the original post (just run msconfig), so this solution is equal to any other