# how to make bat run as admin in inno set up

Tags: windows-7, inno-setup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run a program automatically as admin on Windows startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427673/how-to-run-a-program-automatically-as-admin-on-windows-startup)

I'm working on an installer which will run a bat after install(putting the file name of the bat in run section), and put the bat location to the following reg to let the bat run when users log on.
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run;

On Win7 the bat does not work as admin in both situation, is there any way make the bat run as admin?

Thank you!

Comment: Generally speaking, you cannot. This is a security feature of Windows Vista/7 and above. You cannot work around it via Inno Setup. There are other solutions, such as via a dedicated Windows service application.

Comment: @LexLi Should this be an answer instead?